# Unable to fetch actual value from Web SQL database; it's returning undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, web-sql

Check my code:

```
var db = openDatabase("Despesas", "1.0", "Despesas DB", 2000000);
        db.transaction(createTbl, errorCB, successCB);

        function errorCB(err){
            alert('Error : ' + err.code);
        }
        function successCB(){
            console.log('DB CREATED!');
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
        }
        function createTbl(tx){
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ENTRIES');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTRIES (id integer primary key autoincrement, entry TEXT NOT NULL)');

        }

        function callPopulate(){
            db.transaction(
                function populateDB(tx){        
                    var userInput = document.getElementById('user').value;
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (entry) VALUES (?)', [userInput]);
                    //tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ENTRIES (entry) VALUES ("'+ userInput + '")');
                    //alert('Input ok');
                }, errorCB, successCB);


                }

        function queryDB(tx){
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ENTRIES',[], querySuccess, errorCB);
        }

function querySuccess(tx, results) {

    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '';
    var len = results.rows.length;      
    console.log("ENTRIES table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        item = results.rows.item(i);
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += '<li>' + item.data + '</li>';
        console.log(item);
    }   
}
```

I log `item` to the console, but it prints the Object stored.  I tried `console.log(item.data)`, but it doesn't seem to give me the result I expect.  How am I supposed to fix this and return the real value?  I am using Chrome.

Comment: What exactly does it refer to as `undefined`. i.e. which variable is undefined?

Comment: What does this give you? console.log("dumping the item:",item);

Comment: You calculate length for `results.rows` but use `results.rows.item` and with `()` not with `[]`

Comment: Try to use `item = results.rows[i]` and `console.log(results.rows[i])`

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code (transaction, actual query)? @Victor: that's how [WebSQL results work](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#database-query-results).

Comment: Victor, that does't work =( still undefined....i am trying stuff...

Comment: Well, i can access the value through the storage object like: item.entry, although it shouldnt return undefined right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What will be if you replace `console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);` to `console.log(item);` ?

Comment: Your `ENTRIES` table has columns named `id` and `entry`. There's no `data` column, so you can't expect `item.data` to have a meaningful value.

Comment: HAHA! Stupid error...Thanks DCoder...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have a column called "data" in your table, or you are not selecting it.